# tabularx does not fill full textwidth when using ltablex

Tags: tables, tabularx, ltablex

I had several tables in my document, some longer than others, but all of them defined using `tabularx`. In one moment I decided I needed a way to break tables across pages, so I found out about `ltablex`. With big tables it works really nicely, but with smaller tables, like this:

```
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\hsize=0.2\hsize}X| >{\hsize=2.9\hsize}X | >{\hsize=0.2\hsize}X| >{\hsize=0.7\hsize}X |}
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Snow2}
        \textbf{Nº} & \textbf{Nombre de la unidad} & \textbf{\%} & \textbf{Duración} \\
        \hline
        UT11 & Utilización de frameworks arquitectónicos en cliente & 5 & 5 sesiones \\
        \hline      
    \end{tabularx}
```

Instead of filling the entire width, it just fits the width to the content. The moment I REMOVE the `ltablex` package, it works properly (but I lose the page-breaking feature).

[image: With ltablex]

Is there something that needs to be done?

Also, why does it leave those vertical separations between elements?

Comment: As always on this site please never show sniplets like this, please provide a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is.

Comment: As an alternative to ltablex, you could give xltabular a try.

Comment: Are you in landscape?  Use \linewidth instead of \textwidth.

Comment: Any news? Almost half year ago you get two answer? Does any of them fulfil your expectation (that you would upwote or even accept one of them)?

Answer (score 3):

I am able to reproduce the issue you mention when loading `ltablex`  if I have the geometry package present while using your snippet.

Or using the KOMA-script `\documentclass{scrartcl}` that also sets the geometry of the page.

In both cases it can be controlled with the command `\keepXColumns`. From the manual:

> Another feature that has been added is to treat the X columns like 'l'
> columns if the table contents would allow that to happen without
> exceeding the specified width of the table.
>
> In other words, the specified width is treated as the maximum allowed
> and not the exact width of the table. This feature is the default but
> can be disabled (or enabled) with `\keepXColumns` (or
> `\convertXColumns`).

**Geometry + tabularx**

[image: GTx]

**Geometry + ltablex** (table is 411pt wide)

[image: GLT]

**Geometry + ltablex  + `\keepXColumns`** (table is 483.6pt wide = to `\texwidth`)

[image: GLTk]

**Only  ltablex** (geometry not loaded and article class)

[image: LT]

**Only  tabularx** (geometry not loaded and article class)

[image: tbx]

The two last results are the same since `ltables` uses `tabulax`, but notice the vertical space added before the table by `ltablex`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{ltablex}

%\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage[table,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
    
\keepXColumns   % used with ltablex and geometry

\noindent \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\hsize=0.2\hsize}X| >{\hsize=2.9\hsize}X | >{\hsize=0.2\hsize}X| >{\hsize=0.7\hsize}X |}
    \hline
    \rowcolor{Snow2}
    \textbf{Nº} & \textbf{Nombre de la unidad} & \textbf{\%} & \textbf{Duración} \\
    \hline
    UT11 & Utilización de frameworks arquitectónicos en cliente & 5 & 5 sesiones \\
    \hline      
\end{tabularx}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear, what is your problem. If I a little bit correct your selection of column widths (so, that their contents doesn't overlap) result is just fine:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l| % <--- changed column type
                                  >{\hsize=1.3\hsize}L| 
                                  c| % <--- changed column type
                                  >{\hsize=0.7\hsize}L|}
\caption{Used is \texttt{ltablex} table environment}
\label{my-label}    \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor{Snow2}
\textbf{Nº} & \textbf{Nombre de la unidad} 
                & \textbf{\%}   & \textbf{Duración} \\
    \hline
UT11        & Utilización de frameworks arquitectónicos en cliente 
                & 5             & 5 sesiones        \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```